# android app - make view only take up portion of parent view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-view

I have a background image on my app, and I want my listview to be in the form of a window that overlays the background image. Sort of like the the form which has a white filter in this picture:

http://25.media.tumblr.com/ad75c4a9dad9650ed53d754712f4fbb2/tumblr_mgemxiU2W01r2wjwko2_1280.png

I currently have a listview defined in xml with:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and a semi transparent color as its background. This is great, but it takes up the whole screen, since it fills the parent width and height. What is the best way to make it slightly smaller than the parent's dimensions so that it is say, (fill_parent - some relative value) height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use margin in a layout to make it smaller relative to the parent layout and other child's

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout as a parent, then add your ListView and set width and height to wrap_content. Now it should "float" above the other views inside the FrameLayout. You can use padding and margin to set its position.